# Struct Types Flattening in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a List from a struct type in Spark Data frame. The schema looks something like this

```
root
|
|-- plotList: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|-- plot: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- test: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- body: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- colorPair: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- background: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- foreground: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- eta: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- etaText: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- etaType: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- etaValue: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- headline: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- plotType: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- priority: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- plotCategory: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- productType: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- theme: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- temp: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- body: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- colorPair: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- background: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- foreground: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- eta: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- etaText: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- etaType: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- etaValue: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- headline: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- logo: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- plotType: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- priority: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- plotCategory: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- plotType: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- theme: string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to write a UDF that could convert **plot** column into a List of elements that I can explode in next iteration. Something on the lines of plot --> [test,temp] where I can select some specific columns from within test and temp. Would really appreciate any pointers in right direction. I have tried multiple variations of the UDF but none of them seem to work.

Edit:

I want to create a flattened structure from the subcolumns of the plot column. I am thinking of using a case classes for this. Something like

```
case class ColorPair(back:String, fore:String)
case class Eta(EtaText: String, EtaType: String, EtaValue: String)
case class Plot(body:String, colorPair: ColorPair, eta: Eta, headline: String, plotType: String, priority: String, plotCategory: String, plotType: String, theme: String)
```

So, essentially at the end of this, am expecting something like a `List(Plot)` which then I can `explode` in the subsequent steps. Because explode doesn't work directly on the `Struct Types` I have to go through this transformation. In the python world I would easily read this column as dictionary but nothing like that exists in Scala (that I know of).

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried and why that was not satisfactory? It would really help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: From what I see, it seems that `df.select($"plotList", array($"plot.test", $"plot.temp") as "plot")` would do the trick but I'm not sure I understand what you need.

Comment: @Oli I am trying to generalize the select operation that you have mentioned. Essentially, I am trying to select certain sub columns from test and temp (say eta and plotType) like [(eta,plotType),(eta,plotType)] and in the later stage I will explode this structure. I had tried the select operation as well but that isn't what am looking for. Also, in the actual dataset I have way more elements then temp and test. So, I can't essentially go through all of them manually.

Comment: I think it would greatly help if you could 1. simplify your schema to the minimum instance of the problem (all these fields may not be necessary for us to solve your problem) 2. provide an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Oli The example as shown is the minimum instance of what is required for this problem. A mix of both nested struct types and String types. I have updated the question with what exactly am looking to achieve here. Thanks a ton for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly then you are looking a way to iterate through your schema and when **colorPair** or **eta** is found return these fields as such:

```
plot.test.colorPair
plot.test.eta
plot.temp.colorPair
plot.temp.eta
```

To generate the data(schema) for your case I wrote the next code:

```
  case class Eta(etaText: String, etaType: String, etaValue: String)
  case class ColorPair(background: String, foreground: String)
  case class Test(body: String, colorPair: ColorPair, eta: Eta, headline: String, plotType: String, priority: Long, plotCategory: String, productType: String, theme: String)
  case class Temp(body: String, colorPair: ColorPair, eta: Eta ,headline: String, logo: String, plotType: String, priority: Long, plotCategory: String, productType: String, theme: String)
  case class Plot(test: Test, temp: Temp)
  case class Root(plotList: Array[String], plot: Plot)

  def getSchema(): StructType ={
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
    val schema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Root].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]

    schema.printTreeString()
    schema
  }
```

This will have output:

```
root
 |-- plotList: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- plot: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- test: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- body: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- colorPair: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- background: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- foreground: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- eta: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- etaText: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- etaType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- etaValue: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- headline: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- plotType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- priority: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- plotCategory: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- productType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- theme: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- temp: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- body: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- colorPair: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- background: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- foreground: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- eta: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- etaText: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- etaType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- etaValue: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- headline: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- logo: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- plotType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- priority: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- plotCategory: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- productType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- theme: string (nullable = true)
```

Finally the next code should flatten the desired fields:

```
def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, targetFields: List[String], prefix: String = null): Array[String]=
  {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    schema.fields.flatMap(f => {
      val colName = if (prefix == null) f.name else (prefix + "." + f.name)

      f.dataType match {
        case st : StructType =>
          val found = st.filter(s => targetFields.contains(s.name))

          if(found.isEmpty) {
            flattenSchema(st, targetFields, colName)
          }
          else
            found.flatMap(sf => {
              val st = sf.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
              st.map(st => s"${colName}.${sf.name}.${st.name}")
            })

        case _ => Array[String]()
      }
    })
  }
```

The code above is scanning the schema to find fields that exist in the `targetFields` list, then uses `flatMap` to retrieve the schema for these fields.

This should be the output:

```
plot.test.colorPair.background
plot.test.colorPair.foreground
plot.test.eta.etaText
plot.test.eta.etaType
plot.test.eta.etaValue
plot.temp.colorPair.background
plot.temp.colorPair.foreground
plot.temp.eta.etaText
plot.temp.eta.etaType
plot.temp.eta.etaValue
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @Alexandros. I wanted to use this for selecting column in next stage so I updated the code to return `Array[String](f.name) ` in case the type isn't struct. I tried this but for some reason the code doesn't go till `plot.test.eta.etaText` or anything at 4th level. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @prateek you must use the results in your select statements i.e df.select("data.plot.test.eta.etaText"). In your case you have json data?

Comment: Yeah, I got it working. Even though the explode of the nested stuct is working as expected, it's not what am looking for. I probably will open another question related to that. Accepting your answer as its super helpful in many other use cases. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: ok perfect, so this will go through any schema and extract the path for colorPar and eta

Comment: Also, a more clean implementation for DataFrameFlattener can be found at https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/introduction-to-dataframes-scala.html

Comment: sorry I didnt see that before @Prateek, yes is true although the implementation above is slightly different since it is based on filtering the given specific columns